# Moxi getting locked

Tags: couchbase

I've installed Moxi from couchbase homepage and
put

./moxi -Z usr=****,pwd=****,port_listen=11211,concurrency=1024,wait_queue_timeout=200,connect_timeout=400,connect_max_errors=3,connect_retry_interval=30000,auth_timeout=100,downstream_conn_max=16,downstream_timeout=5000,cycle=200,default_bucket_name=test http://192.168.20.101:8091/pools/default/saslBucketsStreaming

(username and password is written in **** for privacy)

and I have couchbase server up and running on 192.168.20.101

When I do this, it seems like it is stuck in middle of something... I've waited for an hour and still not giving me any messages. Is it supposed to be like this? Or is something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It should be working fine. By default moxi should only log errors and if there are no errors it should log anything to stdout. In order to figure out if there might be an issue I would try to connect your client to moxi and make sure everything makes it to Couchbase. On another note all of the Couchbase SDK's don't require moxi so unless your using a non-Couchbase SDK you don't need to set up any extra moxi processes.

Also, you can try adding the -vvv parameter so that moxi logs on debug level. This will print a lot more to stdout.